# Compare Variable to SQL Column in PHP

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I'd like to compare a variable to a column in my table, So that if the condition is right the query could be executed.
Here's my php code how should I change it ?

```
$money_to_send = $_POST["money_to_send "];
$num_ban = $_POST["num_ban"];
if ($money_to_send < solde_ban){
$statement = "UPDATE ban SET solde_ban = (solde_ban - '$money_to_send') where num_ban = '$num_ban'";

mysqli_query($con, $statement) or die (mysqli_error($con));

$response = array();

$response["success"] = true;
else {$response = array();

$response["success"] = true;}

echo json_encode($response);
```

If anyone could help thanks.

Comment: `"but it doesn't work"` isn't an accurate description. Please can you elaborate what you expect & what you got & how it didn't work..

Comment: I'd like to compare $money_to_send with the solde_ban column. But all what i get is a success response even if my variable value is greater than the solde_ban column.

Comment: Can you show us more code? Looks like something is missing. Where did you get solde_ban. Probably you need another query to fetch data for $num_ban and set $solde_ban. Does it make sense?

Comment: did you really mean , on the if `solde_ban` ???

Comment: Light corrected grammar and formatting

Answer (score 0):

Whenever an `if` statement seems to be "always evaluating to TRUE" or "always evaluating to FALSE", you should take a look the expression and the values of any variables you are using in it.

In this case `$money_to_send` & `solde_ban`.

It looks like a couple things are off:

1) when you are setting the value of `$money_to_send` you have a space at the end of the key name `$_POST["money_to_send "]`  So, check to make sure you're getting a value into your variable.  Just do a `var_dump($money_to_send);` right after you set it.  The trailing space is probably causing the value to get set to `null`

2) `sold_ban` - You need to set the value of this!  You will also need a `$` in front of it. The 'if' statement is currently comparing `null` < string, which is always evaluating to true.

3) also, you're missing a closing `}` in your `if` statement

Working code could look something like this:

```
$money_to_send = $_POST["money_to_send"];
$solde_ban = 555; //some value..!

$num_ban = $_POST["num_ban"];

if ($money_to_send < $solde_ban){
    $statement = "UPDATE ban SET solde_ban = (solde_ban - '$money_to_send') where num_ban = '$num_ban'";
    mysqli_query($con, $statement) or die (mysqli_error($con));
    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = true;
}
else {
    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = true;
}

echo json_encode($response);
```